# adding new records to a subform in access

Tags: winforms, ms-access

Ah!  I think I figured out part of the problem.  I am trying to add a new Line Item by using the PartNumber to control the data in the Line Item.  This won't work because I use PartNumber as the Primary Key in tblPartData; so it won't let me add an new Line Item because of a Key Violation in tblPartData.  What I really need to do is change the FKInvoiceNum.
  Basically I built my queries wrong and got confused.  So I've just spent about 10 hours banging my head against this.  When what I should have done was just written down a describe the problem, and then think about that for awhile.  You know step back and look at it from a different angle.

Thanks for providing me a venue where I had to describe my problem succinctly for others.  But next time I'll write up my question then let it sit for a couple of hours; to save you all some time.

I have an Access Database with a Form and a Subform for an invoicing system based on queries to the following tables:

tblInvoiceData (*InvoiceNum*, *FKCustomerID*, *InvoiceDate*)

tblCustomerData (*CustomerID*, all data pertaining to the customer -- sorry there are about 20 fields)

tblLineItemData (*FKInvoiceNum*, *FKPartNum*)

tblPartData (*PartNumber*, *PartDescription*, *FKManufacturerID*)

qryInvoiceExpandedData (*InvoiceNum*, *FKCustomerID*, *InvoiceDate*, *CustomerID*, and all the Customer data fields)

qryLineItemExpandedData (*FKInvoiceNum*, *FKPartNum*, *PartNumber*, *PartDescription*, *FKManufacturerID*, and all the manufacturer data fields)

The Main form is frmInvoiceDetails and is based on qryInvoiceExpandedData.  The Subform is frmLineItemDetail and is based on qryLineItemExpandedData (includes the following fields: *FKInvoiceNum, FKPartNum, PartNumber, PartDescription, FKManufacturerID, ManufacturerID, ManufacturerName*) as a continues form.

The problem is that in edit or creation mode I can not change any Line Item Data, or add new Line Items.  Can anyone show me where my mistake; I need to be able to change the Line Item Data in the form and can't figure it out.
  Apologies if this question type was answered else where, I was unable to find it -- I expect I'm not asking the right question of the search field.

Comment: add piece of code please

Comment: Not using any code, created the tables, queries and forms using the design mode in Access.

Comment: Show the SQL statement for each query. Edit your question. I expect you have joined tables in qryLineItemExpandedData that results in a non-editable dataset.